# How to check if allow_url_fopen is enabled or not

Tags: php

I'm using the following code

```
echo 'file_get_contents : ', ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';
```

this can get it enabled or disabled

but I would like to make as function say function name is `_isgetcontents`

then I can call it as following any where in my website code

```
if (_isgetcontents()){
  echo "this is enabled"; // will do an action
}else{
  echo "this is disabled"; // will do another action
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `ini_get()` ([docs](https://www.php.net/ini_get)) to get the value of certain configuration parameters:

```
if( \filter_var( \ini_get('allow_url_fopen'), \FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {
   // lucky me...
}
```

Comment: That `if()` is not reliable, as `ini_get()` returns a string of the configuration option, i.e., it could return the string `'Off'` and the conditional would consider it `true`. This should be the right check: `if ( filter_var( ini_get( 'allow_url_fopen' ), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) )`

Comment: That's valid point. I edited my answer to include your filter for those who do not read but do copy&paste coding. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, thanks for changing it. Sometimes I do that myself :)

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this method

> phpinfo()

to check various configurations.

Comment: This does not answer the question as you can't use `phpinfo()` in an `if` statement.

Comment: @Cœur Thanks for correcting me.:)

Comment: In my phpinfo() there isn't this setting!