# Json Decode From URL Not Working

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to use the `mojang api` to retrieve a users `Minecraft UUID` from their Username this is what i have:

```
//Get Player UUID from name
$uuid = "Error obtaining uuid";
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' + $_GET['name']);
$obj = json_decode($json);
$uuid = $obj->id;
```

The variable `$uuid` contains null and im not sure what im doing wrong i made sure i set the `$_GET` parameters by going to `player.php/?name=_Joosh` but still nothing?

Comment: Is there anything on `$json`? Please, `var_dump($json)`, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34486105/edit) your question and post the updates...

Comment: @FirstOne returns: bool(false)

Comment: Please, check if [allow_url_fopen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433660/how-to-check-if-allow-url-fopen-is-enabled-or-not) is enabled. Also, PHP uses `.` to [concat string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: Thank you @FirstOne i was mixing java with php and using + that was my issue, thank you.

Comment: So, the problem was just with the concat part? I mean, is this solved?

Comment: If this is solved, please answer your own question below with the working example and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @joosh, Your concatenation operator is wrong. refer my answer for working sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `dot` opearator for concatenation not plus. Try the below snippet.

```
//Get Player UUID from name
$name = 'john';
$uuid = "Error obtaining uuid";
// Tested with simple variable
// $json = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' . $name);
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' . $_GET['name']);
$obj = json_decode($json);
$uuid = $obj->id;

print $uuid;
```