# I am wanting to print out the geolocation using geoplugin but it returned false

Tags: php, geolocation

when I upload the file that contains this chunk of code to my website it returns false.
 I used unserialize before and it returned false before and after allow_url_open was On. It was on before I checked it was and it still returned false. Any ideas on how to fixed this please? Thank you.

```
<?php 
session_start();       

var_dump(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));      
?>
```

Comment: I am, but I pushed it to the web, to my domain and it returned "bool(false)".

Comment: Use hard coded IP in param instead of `$_SERVER` FOR testing

Comment: Ran fine from my server. Is file_get_contents allowed on your server?

Comment: Is this to be turned on in the php.ini file?

Comment: Use the code in the answer to test http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433660/how-to-check-if-allow-url-fopen-is-enabled-or-not/13433675